# How to pass two list to multiprocessing target function and process the individual list with individual process

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have two list one list contains server name and the second list contains service list.the length of both the list is equal.

```
server_list = [u'server1', u'server2', u'sever3', u'server4']
servive_name = [[u'postfix', u'diamond', u'lldpd', u'ssh', u'nagios-nrpe-server'], [u'postfix', u'lldpd', u'ssh', u'nagios-nrpe-server'], [u'postfix', u'lldpd', u'ssh', u'nagios-nrpe-server'], [u'postfix', u'lldpd', u'ssh', u'nagios-nrpe-server']]
```

i have this function

```
ssh_to_restart(server_name,services,output):
{
 // do ssh on the server and restart the service from service list
}
```

what i want is each process takes the server name and the service list from the respective list (ex- server1 has to map with 1st list in the service_list and so on)and execute the ssh_to_restart() function.
also number of process created with it should be equal to the length of the server_list.
how can i achieve this with something like this code

```
output = multiprocessing.Queue()
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=ssh_to_server, args=(server_list,service_list,output))]
```

EDIT:-

i tried with these codes

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
  pool.map(ssh_to_restart,zip(server_list,service_list))
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

but got this error

```
TypeError: ssh_to_restart() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did solve the problem with

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(4)
pool.map(ssh_to_restart,zip(server_list,service_list))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

the error

```
TypeError: ssh_to_restart() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

was solved by adding double parenthesis around

```
ssh_to_restart((server_name,services,output)):
{
// do ssh on the server and restart the service from service list
}
```

extra parentheses in the definition of insert_and_process - python treat that as a single parameter that should be a 2-item sequence. The first element of the sequence is attributed to the first variable, and the other to the second